# Eclipse Debugger stop just before termination

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I wonder how can you stop the eclipse debugger just before program termination in order to see what happened in the whole process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It won't show you what happened in the whole process -- the stack trace will only show you the current stack, not the execution of previous stacks. I assume if the program has just terminated, then it will have no stack elements anyway! (that's one of the conditions of termination)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by seeing what happened in the whole process? Things aren't recorded, so you can't backtrack the execution.

You can however set a breakpoint in SecurityManager.checkExit if you want to know why the application is terminated.